# SonarQube automatic branch detection

Tags: git, sonarqube

I am trying to achieve automatic detection of branch when doing a sonar build.
in my
`sonar-project.properties`
file, I have the following:

```
sonar.branch=develop
...
```

if I want to run the build, I always have to go back to this file and replace the branch name with the current branch that I am working on and then do an `npm run build:sonar`

I was wondering what the semantic was for doing an automatic build.
I looked at [this](https://github.com/cathive/concourse-sonarqube-resource/commit/6ba588420429b5d27d7044c2b85b212667679796) and also [this](https://github.com/cathive/concourse-sonarqube-resource) and see that it is possible. but didn't see an example as to how to add these properties to my file

Comment: I think this can be achieved by setting the value the sonar call so that it overrides what is written in the properties file. But given that I don't know the details, I am not providing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to avoid using a properties file at all.  Your builds and sonarqube scans should be driven from a scripting technology, like a Jenkinsfile using scripted pipelines (I don't care for declarative pipelines).  Using this, you simply form the entire "sonar-scanner" command line, passing all of the properties you need.  In the Jenkinsfile, there will be a variable that specifies the current branch, so you just put that on the command line and reference it there.